# Alter component on enter-vr event

Tags: aframe

I'm working on my [scrim component](https://github.com/atomicguy/aframe-scrim-component) for A-Frame and want it to "turn off" when VR Mode is entered. Where in the component can I listen for the enter-vr event so I can remove animations?

I add animation settings for opacity on init of the component. I don't know where add a listener for enter-vr to remove the added animation.

```
  init: function () {
    var thisEl = this.el;
    var data = this.data

    var properties = 'property: material.opacity; from: 0; to: 1; dir: alternate; loop: true'
    properties = properties.concat(properties,'; dur: ', data.durration, '; easing: ', data.easing)

    thisEl.setAttribute('animation', properties)

    document.querySelector('a-scene').addEventListener('enter-vr', remove())

  },

  remove: function () {
    var thisEl = this.el;

    thisEl.setAttribute('animation', '')
   },
```

I expected the listener in the init function to call the remove function when enter-vr fires.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow.  To make it easier for folks to answer your question, it helps to include a clear explanation of what you've tried, what you expected to happen and *what happens*.  If you can, feel free to edit your question to include a clear description of what actually happens here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is not correctly attached. Try this instead:

```
document.querySelector('a-scene').addEventListener('enter-vr', this.remove.bind(this));
```

Your code is calling the function and passing the result to `addEventListener` not a reference to the function itself. I recommend reading about function declarations, statements and scoping in JavaScript for better understanding.

Also to remove a component use removeAttribute:

```
thisEl.removeAttribute(“animation”);
```

With setAttribute you are setting the properties to the default values not removing the component. Additional info in docs: https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html#removing-a-component-with-removeattribute

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I'll do some more reading on JavaScript functions.